# Laravel - time difference

Tags: mysql, laravel

Welcome ! I have question to you. I'm coding for myself flight logbook in Laravel 5.2. In formular i'll have time of takeoff and time of arrival and i don't know how to do in laravel count of time difference and pass it automaticly to databas. So at easiest way it'll count this time difference for example: takoeff - 12 UTC arrival - 14UTC and then it'll save this time differece to database as Flight Hours = 2.

Thank u for help

Comment: and in same formular will be place of departure and place of arrival so it should save all to database: place of dep, place of arrival, time of departure, time of arrival and counted flight time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel ships with `Carbon` which provides an easy helper for this:

```
$departure = Carbon::parse($myTakeoffTimestamp); // 12 UTC
$arrival = Carbon::parse($myArrivalTimestamp); // 14 UTC

$diff = $departure->diffInHours($arrival, false); // 2
```

For storing this data:

```
Schema::create('flights', function(Blueprint $table){
    //other table stuff...

    $table->timestamp('departure');
    $table->timestamp('arrival');
    $table->timestamp('duration');
});
```

Then you can just do this in your controller:

```
public function store(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) 
{
    $flight = new Flight;
    $flight->unguard();
    $flight->create([
        //your other flight info
        'departure' = Carbon::parse($myTakeoffTimestamp),
        'arrival' => Carbon::parse($myArrivalTimestamp),
        'duration' => $takeoff->diffInHours($arrival)
    ]);
}
```

As the `timestamp()` definition in your `Schema builder` works flawlessly with `Carbon`'s default formatting (which is a timestamp), there is no extra work to get it into the database with this method.

Comment: ok and how to pass it with one formular to same database? place , time and time difference? as separeted values?